# Deterministic/Pathwise Vs Probabilistic Approach to Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am studying different approaches to solving stochastic differential equations. I keep seeing Ito Calculus being described as a probabilistic approach to solving SDEs, as opposed to being a pathwise approach. Similarly, the Theory of Rough Paths is being described as a deterministic pathwise approach.

I am confused as to what it means for an approach to be pathwise when integrating a stochastic process driven by Brownian Motion. How is it possible to just ignore/remove the probabilistic/random qualities of an SDE. Does this mean that we a fix a random path/trajectory of the Brownian Motion and integrate simply with respect to that?

Thanks

Comment: A "random path/trajectory of the Brownian Motion" is just any continuous function. The Brownian motion defines a (dynamic) measure on the space of continuous functions (any BM can be modified on a nullset to have all paths continuous). But how to you "simply integrate"? The Riemann-Stieltjes integral, e.g., demands finite total variation. So you get back to the Ito integral (or other related constructions) to make sense of $\int \sigma dB$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to simulate pathwise the (strong) solution of the SDE $$dX_t=X_t\,dW_t$$ by discretizing using, say, the Euler scheme:
$$
X_{t_i}=X_{t_{i-1}}+X_{t_{i-1}}\sqrt{t_i-t_{i-1}}\,\varepsilon_k
$$
where you draw $\varepsilon_k$ independently from $N(0,1)$ every time you need one such $\varepsilon_k$
(you will need $nm$ such draws when your time interval has $n$ points and you simulate $m$ paths).

That SDE has the advantage of having a closed form solution
$$
X_t=X_0\,e^{W_t-t/2}
$$
which you can compare with the simulation.

In short: ***strong*** solutions of SDEs can be understood as pathwise solutions: every path $\omega$ of $t\mapsto W_t(\omega)$ of the given Brownian motion leads to a path $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ of the solution.

[Rough paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path#:%7E:text=In%20stochastic%20analysis%2C%20a%20rough,the%201990s%20by%20Terry%20Lyons) seems to be a topic for specialists in control theory. I know nothing about that.